# imagecreatefrompng() with generated png from a php file

Tags: php, png, content-type, imagecreatefrompng

I am getting error with this code

```
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 

$nomphoto = "antigua.jpg";

// On charge d'abord les images
$source = imagecreatefrompng('logo.php');


$destination = imagecreatefromjpeg($nomphoto); 


$largeur_source = imagesx($source);
$hauteur_source = imagesy($source);
$largeur_destination = imagesx($destination);
$hauteur_destination = imagesy($destination);



$destination_x = 0;
$destination_y =  ($hauteur_destination / 1.5) - ($hauteur_source / 2);


imagecopymerge($destination, $source, $destination_x, $destination_y, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source, 60);


imagejpeg($destination);
```

I cannot load the pictures from **logo.php**

*Code of logo.php*

```
$imgPng = imagecreatefrompng("logo24.png");
imagealphablending($imgPng, true);
imageSaveAlpha($imgPng, true);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($imgPng);
```

I want to put a copyright with my png-24 image. logo.php is working fine, I can get the picture but when I use it with imagecreatefrompng, it is not working.

I tried with *imagecreatefrompng(file_get_contents('logo.php'));* but it is also not working.
What I want is put my png-24 copyright image on my jpg (to keep transparency) 
You guyz do you have any solutions?

Comment: Was not the problem... It was imagecopymerge() which is not working with png-24. imagecopy() does it !

Comment: Nice job on solving it yourself :) When you can, please write the solution as an answer and mark it as solved.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Instead of using **imagecopymerge()**, have to use **imagecopy()**

```
imagecopy($destination, $source, $destination_x, $destination_y, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source);
```

And then don't need to *logo.php* code. Just load the png-24 image.